# 'Comparable' interface - why global

Tags: apex

In Apex, why are the interfaces like 'Comparable' kept global? What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is thankfully now no longer a requirement, something the samples in the documentation have yet to catchup with. Despite the samples (including the Batch Apex ones) suggesting otherwise, you can use **public**. As per the documentation for [Comparable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm) these days...

> The implemented method must be declared as **global** or **public**.

As to why global was required in the past, i suspect it may have been down to some kind of versioning implementation between the platform and our code. Thankfully Salesforce figured out a better way to achieve this with interfaces and avoid us having to expose our logic via global.

Comment: I think global was previously required because interfaces were meant to allow System.Type reflection to load classes outside the current namespace to extend functionality. As a side effect, system interfaces were also global, causing the problem of exposing classes. Surely, they fixed this because comparable was near useless in a global context; us developers ended up writing the same sort algorithms instead of using comparable.

Comment: @sfdcfox makes a very important point. Say your class is implementing an interface defined in a base package.  If your implementation class is **public**, then code *in the base package* will NOT be able to find / interact with it --- whereas if your implementation class is **global**, then code in the base package WILL be able to find / interact with it. So the fact that an implemented method CAN now be declared as public does not mean that you should/will be able to declare it as public and have the same functionality as if it were declared global.

Comment: That is a good point @zachelrath, though this question, unless i misunderstood it, relates to system interfaces, your points regarding exposure of custom Apex interfaces and/or implementation classes are spot on though.